# Average food packet delivery timing for user - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I m looking to get an average delivery time for each individual customers.
Delivery is divided into 4 steps, if delivery is cancelled before 4th step then this delivery should not be considered in calculation. The table contains customer_id,delivery_step and time_stamp  [image]

Orders of different customers can overlap although.

---

---

Following statements can be used to create table and sample data:-

```
> create table  delivery (customer_id number, delivery_step number ,
> time_stamp timestamp  ); insert into delivery (customer_id,
> delivery_step , time_stamp ) values (1,1,TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01
> 12:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')); insert into delivery
> (customer_id, delivery_step , time_stamp ) values
> (1,2,TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01 12:10:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
> insert into delivery (customer_id, delivery_step , time_stamp ) values
> (1,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-01 12:05:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
> insert into delivery (customer_id, delivery_step , time_stamp ) values
> (2,1,TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-02 18:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
> insert into delivery (customer_id, delivery_step , time_stamp ) values
> (1,1,TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-02 18:05:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
> insert into delivery (customer_id, delivery_step , time_stamp ) values
> (1,2,TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-02 12:15:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
> insert into delivery (customer_id, delivery_step , time_stamp ) values
> (1,3,TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-02 12:15:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
> insert into delivery (customer_id, delivery_step , time_stamp ) values
> (1,4,TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-01-02 12:15:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
> 
> select * from delivery;
```

I unable to get the result using 1 SQL query.Would anyone please help me to determine result using 1 query.

Expected Result :-

```
customer | total time 
--------------------------------
1        |   6 h 10 min
```

Comment: With only that data this appears impossible to be 100% accurate. Is there any further information you have, for example can a customer ID order two separate deliveries that overlap each other?

Comment: Expected Result?

Comment: Just looking at your data, how would you distinguish between 'cancelled' and simply 'not yet completed the next step? For instance, you have only 1 row for customer_id=2, and that at delivery_step=1.  So, has that order been cancelled, or are we just waiting for step 2 to complete? How can you tell?

Comment: For any customer if all steps are present 1,2,3,4 then only we will consider it as completed, otherwise it should not be used in calculation. (1 or 1,2 or ,1,2,3  row are not considered in absence of step 4 ). Only 1 completed delivery for each customer in table.

Comment: @Ankit Bajpai expected result updated in post

Comment: Is the third row really meant to happen *before* the second row? I think the heart of this problem is that we have to infer the order from the number of delivery steps and the time, but if the time is out of order then I don't see any way to answer this question. (Or can we simply throw out the third row because it happens out of order?)

Answer (score 0):

You may try below query -

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,
       EXTRACT(HOUR FROM MAX(TIME_STAMP) - MIN(TIME_STAMP)) || 'H ' || 
       EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM MAX(TIME_STAMP) - MIN(TIME_STAMP)) || 'M' TOTAL_TIME
  FROM (SELECT D.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER_ID, DELIVERY_STEP ORDER BY DELIVERY_STEP, TIME_STAMP DESC) RN
          FROM delivery D)
 WHERE RN = 1
 GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DELIVERY_STEP) = 4
```

[Link.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ae71afd076971d1279cb24e55d3b9bc5)